# What is the integrating factor of this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I've been trying to solve this differential equation:
$$\frac{y}{x^2}(2+x^3y)dx-\frac{1}{x^2}(1-2x^3y)dy=0$$
The methods I've tried to produce the integrating factor for it don't seem to be working. How should I go about this?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti I evaluated $\frac{1}{N}(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial x})$ and $\frac{1}{M}(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial x})$ and I tried to equate co-efficients after assuming the integrating factor is of the form $x^my^n$

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. This makes it easier to answer, and if these questions are all related, you can transfer the skills answering one question to the other questions.